# Camera keep changing it's colors from light red to light green every 0.25 sec (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: drivers, video, webcam, monitor, cheese

when I lunch Cheese Webcam Booth this is what the picture looks like

[image: light green screen]
[image: light red screen]

and it keeps changing between these 2 colors every 0.25 sec

Answer (score 1):

I recommend going to **Preferences -> Image** and changing the Hue level. Simply changing it should set a value to it (In the case there is no default value set). You should know that Cheese has some problems that could come back from one version to another. This is why I have a backup like `Kamerka` or `Kamoso` which are found in the Software Center and do not suffer from several Cheese related issues.

Another factor that could cause this is the resolution. Try changing the Cheese resolution to one smaller/bigger and see how it behaves.

If changing the Hue or changing the resolution does not solve the issue file a bug report and try to use one of the other recommended meanwhile.

Comment: I tried everything u said ,and installed Kamerka and Kamoso but still the same problem ,it's probably a bug

Comment: If you think it's a bug please file a report. It is very important this could help others.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to use any Effects by mistake (bottom right button)? Have you tried to differently lighted room (lighter or darker)?

Comment: yea I checked that,it's on No Effect